# How do I clean a vintage carbon steel pastry cutter?

Tags: cleaning, carbon-steel

How do I remove old rusty spots from a 70-year-old pastry blender & make "food safe"?

Prefer not to use polishes or other volatile, caustic products.

Comment: It takes a LOT of rust to not be food safe.

Comment: Rusty, rough/porous surfaces can be difficult to clean and thus sanitize though .. on the other hand, pastry blenders are usually  used on ingredients that won't be consumed raw :)

Answer (score 3):

Look up what has been written on restoring carbon steel knives, similar techniques apply.

To clean up loose rust, steel wool, sandpaper and wire brushes will help; afterwards, you might want to try and build a patina by treating it with a food-safe acid (vinegar, lemon...).

Comment: Not going to build a patina on iron.  Iron will rust.  Treat it with a food-safe acid will just cause more rust.

Comment: How is the unhardened or mildly hardened steel (being literal iron is unlikely) in such tools different from eg soft cladding steel on a knife?

Comment: Rust https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust  Patina https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patina  Do you have any evidence lemon juice  will produce a patina on a steel knife.

Comment: What would technically be "stable rust" is usually called patina with carbon steel kitchen equipment.

Comment: Please provide a reference on "stable rust".

Comment: @Paparazzi - the article you linked on patina did mention forming it on carbon steel knives with the use of acid - not lemon, specifically, but muriatic acid, apple cider vinegar or mustard, or "any acidic vegetables or fruits".  Its at the very bottom of the section on applied patinas.

Comment: And btw, everyone who has carbon steel knives knows fruit will do exactly that to hardened carbon steel (iron cladding is another matter, it will rust if not meticulously cleaned) ... the achetypical german grandmother will have a Herder parer that won't rust away while nobody ever removes the patina ;)

Answer (score 0):

So for a liquid non-toxic cleaner go with Enviro Care Washroom Cleaner. (I know right!?!) It's made in the US.

Pastry cutters are odd shaped and have hard to get at spots. Soaking is better than spraying to get right into those spots.

Soapy water and a Scotch Brite pad (lightly) is useful after the soak.
Rinse and dry thoroughly.

Comment: So do you have experience using this chemical cleaner with non-stainless steels?

Answer (score 0):

Mechanical abrasion, using sandpaper or steel wool or wire brushes, should work to get most of the rust off the surface of the pastry cutter.  rackandboneman's answer has already mentioned this, I confess.

After the rust, or most of the rust, has been removed - you might try seasoning the pastry cutter, to prevent it from rusting in the future.  You should be able to build up an [oil-based seasoning](http://www.seriouseats.com/2008/02/in-gear-how-to-season-carbon-steel-pans.html), brushing on thin layers and heating to form thin layers of seasoning.  You might be able to build up a [tea-based seasoning](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/43950/why-dont-i-have-to-season-my-cast-iron-teapot), soaking it in thickly brewed boiling tea and letting dry, again several times, to build up layers of tannins deposited on the surface.  I expect your choice might have to do with what sorts of products you expect the pastry cutter to be used with, and which you wouldn't mind wearing off into your pastry.

Both techniques are usually used to keep cast iron from rusting (the oil-based usually for frying pans, the tea-based for teapots).  But, I see no reason that they can't be used to form a protective coating for your carbon steel pastry cutter to prevent rusting, if you're uncertain about rackandboneman's suggestion of using acid to build a patina with acid.

I would think that the pastry cutter should rarely need re-seasoning, I don't imagine it will get a lot of really hard use of the sort that will wear the seasoning away, but you can of course repeat the seasoning process whenever needed.